# MSSQL Win HTTP 5.1 ignore certificate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, http, winhttp

I'm trying to to create an https request from a stored procedure in MSSQL to a https website using WinHttpRequest 5.1. I have managed to create the request to a normal http website using OLE automation procedures (sp_OACreate, sp_OAMethod, etc..) but i need to set the WinHTTP object to ignore any certificate errors.

WinHttp 5.1 itself supports this option but i do not know how to set it from MSSQL unfortunately

Here is what i should do in MSSQL:

```
http.Option[WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags] = SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the [`Option`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383998(v=vs.85).aspx) property with [`sp_OASetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oasetproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  You need the integer values for `WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags` and `SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All`.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have tried `EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @Object, '4', '13056'` (13056 = 0x3300 = SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All) and it returns **Unknown name.**

Comment: You're welcome. Now mark the answer as correct so that your question does not remain unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: Done. I'll write here the exact line of code that worked for me `EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @Object, 'Option', '13056', 4` where 13056 = 0x3300 = SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All and 4 = int value of WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags